# Buscar parte de un string alojado en un array

Tags: javascript

```js
const self      = this;
self.diasSemana = ["Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado","Domingo"];

self.buscar = () => {
   palabra = document.getElementById("busqueda").value;
   console.log(self.diasSemana.indexOf(palabra))
  return self.diasSemana.indexOf(palabra)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="busqueda" onkeyup="buscar()">
```

Mi probelma es que quiero buscar una parte de un string alojado dentro de un array, por ejemplo tengo un array de dias:

`let dias = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes"];`

Ahora en un input de texto con solo poner `lu` me debería regresar la posición del array donde se encuentra, tengo pensado que es con `indexOf` pero no se como implementarlo

Cuando se busca toda la palabra claramente si funciona correctamente pero se tendría que anidar la busqueda para que funcione al buscar solo un fragmento de la palabra.

**Edit**: dejo parte del codigo que estoy usando:

Comment: Hola. Que has intentado hasta ahora? Puedes poner algo de código?

Answer (score 2):

Lo solucione con un `for in`, básicamente en cada palabra contenida en el arreglo se hace uso del método `indexOf` y solo retorno la posición del arreglo en que se encontró la coincidencia:

```js
const self      = this;
self.diasSemana = ["lunes","martes","miercoles","jueves","viernes","sabado","domingo"];

self.buscar = () => {
   palabra = document.getElementById("busqueda").value;
  for(dia in self.diasSemana){
   if(self.diasSemana[dia].indexOf(palabra) != -1){
      console.log(self.diasSemana[dia])
    return dia;
   }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="busqueda" onkeyup="buscar()">
```